# Problem installing/rebuilding Xdebug under Apple Silicon M1

Tags: xdebug, apple-silicon

Failing to install XDebug under the new Apple Silicon M1 under Big Sur - After using `pecl install xdebug` and running `php --ini` I am getting the following error:

```
PHP Warning:  Failed loading Zend extension 'xdebug.so' (tried: /opt/homebrew/lib/php/pecl/20190902/xdebug.so (dlopen(/opt/homebrew/lib/php/pecl/20190902/xdebug.so, 9): no suitable image found.  Did find:
        /opt/homebrew/lib/php/pecl/20190902/xdebug.so: mach-o, but wrong architecture
        /opt/homebrew/lib/php/pecl/20190902/xdebug.so: stat() failed with errno=22), /opt/homebrew/lib/php/pecl/20190902/xdebug.so.so (dlopen(/opt/homebrew/lib/php/pecl/20190902/xdebug.so.so, 9): image not found)) in Unknown on line 0

Warning: Failed loading Zend extension 'xdebug.so' (tried: /opt/homebrew/lib/php/pecl/20190902/xdebug.so (dlopen(/opt/homebrew/lib/php/pecl/20190902/xdebug.so, 9): no suitable image found.  Did find:
        /opt/homebrew/lib/php/pecl/20190902/xdebug.so: mach-o, but wrong architecture
        /opt/homebrew/lib/php/pecl/20190902/xdebug.so: stat() failed with errno=22), /opt/homebrew/lib/php/pecl/20190902/xdebug.so.so (dlopen(/opt/homebrew/lib/php/pecl/20190902/xdebug.so.so, 9): image not found)) in Unknown on line 0
```

I tried recompiling xdebug from source (`git clone git://github.com/xdebug/xdebug.git`) with the same results. Can I force the correct architecture in the `config.m4` when recompiling xdebug? - ANy other suggestions?

Comment: I tried with this before doing phpize: ./configure --enable-xdebug CC="gcc -arch x86_64" CXX="g++ -arch x86_64"
But now I got: "code signature in (/usr/local/lib/php/pecl/20200930/xdebug.so) not valid for use in process using Library Validation: mapped file has no cdhash, completely unsigned? Code has to be at least ad-hoc signed"

Answer (score 15):

I needed to specify the architecture.
It worked with :

```
arch -arm64 sudo pecl install xdebug
```

Comment: The -arm64 fixed it for me on Apple M1 BigSur 11.6

Comment: This worked for me as well, on Apple M1 BigSur 11.5.1 (macbook air 2020)

Comment: it's worked for me on Mackbook Pro 2020 and my macOS is Big Sur 11.4

Answer (score 5):

Simply open your php.ini file and replace this line:

`zend_extension="xdebug.so"`

with whatever the installation process offered you
[image]

in my case it's:
`/opt/homebrew/Cellar/php/8.1.5/pecl/20210902/xdebug.so`

And remember to restart your services!

Answer (score 3):

tried install with `pecl install xdebug` and got this error:

```
Build process completed successfully
Installing '/opt/homebrew/Cellar/php@7.4/7.4.15_1/pecl/20190902/xdebug.so'

Warning: mkdir(): File exists in System.php on line 294

Warning: mkdir(): File exists in /opt/homebrew/Cellar/php@7.4/7.4.15_1/share/php@7.4/pear/System.php on line 294
ERROR: failed to mkdir /opt/homebrew/Cellar/php@7.4/7.4.15_1/pecl/20190902
```

I used fix from this link https://patriqueouimet.ca/tip/installing-php-and-pecl-extensions-on-macos and it helped

Your warnings are about architecture, maybe need to remove and install again - i was do all from arm64 terminal...

Answer (score 2):

On a fresh MacOS installation I was getting an error:

`Warning: mkdir(): File exists in System.php on line 294 PHP Warning:  mkdir(): File exists in /usr/local/Cellar/php/7.3.3/share/php/pear/System.php on line 294`

`Warning: mkdir(): File exists in /usr/local/Cellar/php/7.3.3/share/php/pear/System.php on line 294 ERROR: failed to mkdir /usr/local/Cellar/php/7.3.3/pecl/20180731`

You simply need to make the directory the script cannot, to accomplish this, run the following:

`pecl config-get ext_dir | pbcopy`

`mkdir -p {paste clipboard value}`

Now you can install PECL extensions

`pecl install xdebug`

Answer (score 1):

You will likely have to install Xdebug through PECL with:

```
arch -x86_64 sudo pecl install xdebug
```

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if this was the problem. However, I did a full reset of my M1 Macbook. And this time I only used arm software (iterm, homebrew...), this time it installed without any issue.